# Which is worse: 'decliner' or 'détraquer'

Tags: vocabulaire

In a headline: '[La France ne décline pas, elle se détraque](https://www.lesechos.fr/idees-debats/editos-analyses/la-france-ne-decline-pas-elle-se-detraque-1891485)', I can't tell which is worse 'decliner' or 'détraquer'.  So if the former is worse it would be translated as: 'France is not declining, it's merely in a temporary funk', otherwise it would be translated as: 'France is not declining, it's going to the dogs'.

Comment: Contexte auteur etc. : [Éric Le Boucher](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89ric_Le_Boucher)

Answer (score 2):

*Détraquer* is not particularly better or worse than *décliner*. They're a bit different. *Décliner* means that something is becoming inferior to what it used to be. *Décliner* is somewhat gradual. *Déclin* can be temporary or permanent, although in a political context it's implied to be permanent, alluding to the decline of the Roman Empire. *Détraquer* means that something is partially broken: it's still working to some extent, but not working well. There is usually an implication that it can be repaired, but this is not an obligation.

That's for the strictly lexicographic answer. But there is a political context here. You didn't quote the origin, but I can hasard a guess. *Décliner* is a common complaint among people who regret that today isn't the good old days of yesterday. This headline implies that all readers would consider it a fact that France is declining, in order to bring a twist to this idea. The twist is that the complaint about today not being the good old days is a *détraquement* rather than a *déclin*.

An important implication of *détraquement* is that it comes from the inside and can be fought from the inside. *Déclin*, in contrast, might be inevitable. (That's not the same thing as permanent. Days decline in the fall; you can't help that but you can wait for spring.) *Détraquement*, in a political context, implies that there are people inside who are guilty of making France not as great as it should be. I presume the article goes on to name those enemies.

Comment: Je sais que c'est contre-intuitif, mais les jours commencent à rallonger en hiver.

Comment: @jlliagre Ça dépend du déclin ?  Si c'est le déclin de la température, oui ; la longueur de la journée, non, solstice gratias.

Comment: @livresque Je nitpiquais mais quand on dit "les jours déclinent", je comprends "les jours raccourcissent" plutôt que "la température baisse". *Aout, septembre et octobre, c'est au Bosphore la saison delicieuse, où le ciel a des limpidités édéniques, **où les jours declinent**, se recueillent et s’apaisent, mais en gardant la splendeur.* Pierre Loti, Les désenchantées, 1906.